# unable to stop Audio Recording,Thread not working properly and application stops unfortunately

Tags: android, multithreading, audio

I am making a sample program for recording audio.I have a button for starting and stopping the recording.I am running a thread so that i can record until 30 sec.My problem is when before reaching to 30sec ,if i click on stopButton ,my application stops unfortunately.Now i am not getting the problem.
Following is my code:

```
public class AudioRecordingActivity extends Activity {
private Button RecordButton;
boolean recording;
MediaRecorder recorder ;
Thread RecordThread;
Handler recordHandler;
private TextView timeText;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    timeText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    RecordButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRecord);
    RecordButton.setText("Start Recording");
    RecordButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(-16711936, 0)); 
    recording=false;
    RecordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (recording)
            {

                 recording=false;

                stopRecording();
                RecordButton.setText("Start Recording");
                RecordButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(-16711936, 0)); 
             // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            }//if(recording)
            else if(!recording) {

                recording=true;
                startRecording();
                RecordButton.setText("Stop Recording");
                RecordButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(-65536, 0));
            //    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                recordHandler = new Handler();
                  RecordThread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
                      int j;
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        for( j=30;j>=0;j--){
                            if(recording){
                                recordHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    setTimer(j);
                                    }//handler run

                                });//post
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }//catch
                            }else if (!recording)
                            {
                                stopRecording();

                            }
                        }//for
                    }//run  

                });
                RecordThread.start();


            }


        }
    });


}//onCreate
protected void startRecording() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 1000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
     File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/AudioRecord");
      if(!folder.exists())
        {
          folder.mkdirs();

        } 
       String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
            "/AudioRecord/audiorecord"+n+".3gp";                  



    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setOutputFile(path);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Saving Audio as"+ path,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IllegalStateException called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "prepare() failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

      recorder.start();


}

 private void stopRecording() {

     recorder.stop();
     recorder.release();
     recorder = null;


    }

    private void setTimer(int j) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(String.valueOf(j) + "sec");
        if(j==0){
            recording=false;

        }


    }
}//class end
```

Audio is been recorded perfectly.I guess the problem is with stopping the audio and thread.I don't know where the correction are to be made.
THanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you post a log of the error?

Comment: i am getting error on phone..My app is stopping unfortunately when i click on stop button...

Comment: It would be of great help if you could post the log from the telephone as the problem happens. Do this by opening a terminal window and type 'adb logcat'. Reproduce the problem and copy paste the text from the window.

Comment: hey got d correction..following changes were made..thnks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: Following corrections were made..

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (recording)
            {
                if(recorder!=null){
                     recorder.stop();
                     recorder.release();
                     recorder = null;
                }

                recording=false;
                RecordButton.setText("Start Recording");
                RecordButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(-16711936, 0)); 
             // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            }
```

...

```
private void setTimer(int j) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         timeText.setText(String.valueOf(j) + "sec"); 
         if ((recording) && (j==1)){

                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
                recorder = null;
                recording=false;
                RecordButton.setText("Start Recording");
                RecordButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(-16711936, 0)); 

            }





    }
```